# Using different data for positioning and display of labels in plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

*TL;DR: with plot labels using `geom_label` etc., is it possible to use different data for the calculation of positions of using `position_stack` or similar functions, than for the display of the label itself? Or, less generally, is it possible to subset the label data **after** positions have been calculated?*

I have some time series data for many different subjects. Observations took place at multiple time points, which are the same for each subject. I would like to plot this data as a stacked area plot, where the height of a subject's curve at each time point corresponds to the observed value for that subject at that time point. **Crucially, I also need to add labels to identify each subject.**

However, the trivial solution of adding one label at each observation makes the plot unreadable, so I would like to limit the displayed labels to the "most important" subjects (the ones that have the highest peak), as well as only display a label at the respective peak. This subsetting of the labels themselves is not a problem either, but I cannot figure out how to then position the (subset of) labels correctly so they match with the stacked area chart.

Here is some example code, which should work out of the box with `tidyverse` installed, to illustrate my issue. First, we generate some data which has the same structure as mine:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)

# Generate some data
num_subjects = 50
num_timepoints = 10
labels = paste(sample(words, num_subjects), sample(fruit, num_subjects), sep = "_")
col_names = c("name", paste0("timepoint_", c(1:num_timepoints)))
df = bind_rows(map(labels,
                   ~c(., cumsum(rnorm(num_timepoints))) %>%
                     set_names(col_names))) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("timepoint_"), names_to = "timepoint", names_prefix = "timepoint_") %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(c("timepoint", "value")), as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value < 0, 0, value)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% mutate(peak = max(value)) %>% ungroup()
```

Now, we can trivially make a simple stacked area plot without labels:

```r
# Plot (without labels)
ggplot(df,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = factor(peak))) +
  geom_area(show.legend = FALSE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[Plot without labels (it appears that I currently cannot embed images, which is very unfortunate as they are extremely illustrative here...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAA2A.png)

It is also not too hard to add non-specific labels to this data. They can easily be made to appear at the correct position — so the center of the label is at the middle of the area for each time point and subject — using `position_stack`:

```r
# Plot (all labels, positions are correct but the plot is basically unreadable)
ggplot(df,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = factor(peak))) +
  geom_area(show.legend = FALSE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  geom_label(mapping = aes(label = name), show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[Plot with a label at each observation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/845Z3.png)

However, as noted before, the labels almost entirely obscure the plot itself. So my approach would be to only show labels at the peaks, and only for the 10 subjects with the highest peaks:

```r
# Plot (only show labels at the peak for the 10 highest peaks, readable but positions are wrong)
max_labels = 10 # how many labels to show
df_labels = df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% slice_max(value, n = 1) %>% ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(value, n = max_labels)

ggplot(df,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = factor(peak))) +
  geom_area(show.legend = FALSE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  geom_label(data = df_labels, mapping = aes(label = name), show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[Plot with only a subset of labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsl9U.png)

This code also works fine, but it is apparent that the labels no longer show up at the correct positions, but are instead too low on the plot, especially for the subjects which would otherwise be higher up. (The only subject where the position is correct is `work_eggplant`.) This makes perfect sense, as the data used for calculation of `position_stack` are now only a subset of the original data, so the observations which would receive no labels are not considered when stacking. This can be illustrated by zeroing out all the observations which would not receive a label:

```r
df_zeroed = anti_join(df %>% mutate(value = 0),
                      df_labels,
                      by = c("name", "timepoint")) %>% bind_rows(df_labels)
ggplot(df_zeroed,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = factor(peak))) +
  geom_area(show.legend = FALSE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  geom_label(data = df_labels, mapping = aes(label = name), show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
```

[Plot with unlabeled observations zeroed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu1lB.png)

So now my question is, how can this problem be solved? Is there a way to use the original data for the positioning, but the subset data for the actual display of the labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. To achieve the desired result you could

1. use the whole dataset for plotting the labels to get the right positions,
2. use an empty string `""` for the non-desired labels ,
3. set the `fill` and `color` of non-desired labels to `"transparent"`

```r
# Plot (only show labels at the peak for the 10 highest peaks, readable but positions are wrong)
max_labels = 10 # how many labels to show
df_labels = df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice_max(value, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(value, n = max_labels) %>% 
  mutate(label = name)

df1 <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_labels) %>% 
  replace_na(list(label = ""))
#> Joining, by = c("name", "timepoint", "value", "peak")

ggplot(df1,
       mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = as.character(peak))) +
  geom_area(show.legend = FALSE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  geom_label(mapping = aes(
    label = label,
    fill = ifelse(label != "", as.character(peak), NA_character_),
    color = ifelse(label != "", "black", NA_character_)), 
    show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(na.value = "transparent") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black" = "black"), na.value = "transparent")
```

[image]

**EDIT** If you want the fill colors to correspond to the value of peak then

1. a simple solution would be to map `peak` on `fill` instead of `factor(peak)` and make use of `fill = ifelse(label != "", peak, NA_real_)` in `geom_label`. However, in that case you have to switch to a continuous fill scale.
2. as I guess that you had a good reason to make use of discrete scale an  other option would be to make `peak` an orderd factor. This approach however is not that simple. To make this work I first reorder `factor(peak)` according to peak, add an additional NA level and make us of an auxilliary variable `peak1` to fill the labels. However, as we have two different variables to be mapped on `fill` I would suggest to make use of a second fill scale using `ggnewscale::new_scale_fill` to achieve the desired result:

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(0)
#cumsum(rnorm(num_timepoints)) * 3
# Generate some data
num_subjects = 50
num_timepoints = 10
labels = paste(sample(words, num_subjects), sample(fruit, num_subjects), sep = "_")
col_names = c("name", paste0("timepoint_", c(1:num_timepoints)))
df = bind_rows(map(labels,
                   ~c(., cumsum(rnorm(num_timepoints)) * 3) %>%
                     set_names(col_names))) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("timepoint_"), names_to = "timepoint", names_prefix = "timepoint_") %>%
  mutate(across(all_of(c("timepoint", "value")), as.numeric)) %>%
  mutate(value = if_else(value < 0, 0, value)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>% mutate(peak = max(value)) %>% ungroup()

# Plot (only show labels at the peak for the 10 highest peaks, readable but positions are wrong)
max_labels = 10 # how many labels to show
df_labels = df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  slice_max(value, n = 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  slice_max(value, n = max_labels) %>% 
  mutate(label = name)

df1 <- df %>% 
  left_join(df_labels) %>% 
  replace_na(list(label = ""))
#> Joining, by = c("name", "timepoint", "value", "peak")


df2 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(
    # Make ordered factor
    peak = fct_reorder(factor(peak), peak),
    # Add NA level to peak
    peak = fct_expand(peak, NA),
    # Auxilliary variable to set the fill to NA for non-desired labels
    peak1 = if_else(label != "", peak, factor(NA))) 

ggplot(df2, mapping = aes(x = factor(timepoint), y = value, group = name, fill = peak)) +
  geom_area(show.legend = TRUE, position = "stack", colour = "gray25") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(na.value = "transparent") +
  # Add a second fill scale
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_label(mapping = aes(
    label = label,
    fill = peak1, 
    color = ifelse(label != "", "black", NA_character_)), 
    show.legend = FALSE, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(na.value = "transparent") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black" = "black"), na.value = "transparent")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this solution is a bit less clean than I hoped but it definitely solves my problem. However, it seems like doing this causes the peaks (and thus the colour assignment) to get sorted alphabetically instead of numerically. This can be seen if you use higher values (e.g. `cumsum(rnorm(num_timepoints)) * 3`): https://i.imgur.com/eWdFYhN.png (here I also enabled the legend so it's especially apparent). Do you know how this could be solved?

Comment: Hi Shizundeiku. Hm. To the best of my knowledge this the cleanest solution to achieve your desired result. (; Concerning the fill colors. That's not an issue of my solution. I just borrowed this from your code, i.e. you map `factor(peak)` on `fill`, while I use `as.character(fill)`. But that doesn't matter. Both result in an alphabetical order. I just made an edit which includes two options to solve this issue.